# For functions $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset L^p, f \in L^p$ prove equivalent condition to convergence in p-norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

For $p \in [1,\infty)$ let $f, f_n \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that TFAE:
$i) \: f_n \to f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ as $n \to \infty$
$ii) \: f_n \to f$ in $L^p([-N,N])$ as $n \to \infty$ $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lVert f_n \rVert_p \to \lVert f\rVert_p$.

I was able to show the implication $i) \implies ii)$.
For the other implication I tried:
$\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x) -f_n(x)|^p dx = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \lim \limits_{N \to \infty}\mathbf{1}_{[-N,N]}(x) \cdot |f(x) -f_n(x)|^p dx \\
= \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{[-N,N]}(x) |f(x) -f_n(x)|^p dx$ 
and then taking $n \to \infty$ exchanging the limits somehow.

The second equality is justified by dominated convergence, dominating $\mathbf{1}_{[-N,N]}(x) |f(x) -f_n(x)|^p$ by $|f(x) -f_n(x)|^p$ which is integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer, as written at the time of acceptance, was incomplete. Thanks to **@Ruy** for the heads up.*

For the other implication, use the following lemma:

*Lemma*: If $f \in L^p (\mathbb{R})$ and $E_N \uparrow \mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\left(
\int_{E_N^C} |f|^p \mathrm{d}\lambda
\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\to 0
$$
as $N \to \infty$.

To prove this lemma, define the measure $|f|^p \mathrm{d} \lambda$ and use the (upper) continuity of measures.

Now, define $E_N = [-N, N], g^N = f \cdot \chi_{E_N}$ and $g^N_n = f_n \cdot \chi_{E_N}$.
By Minkowski's inequality, we have
$$
||f - f_n||_p \leq ||f - g^N||_p + ||g^N - g^N_n||_p + ||g^N_n - f_n||_p
.$$

If we let $n \to \infty$, we know the central term goes to $0$. Our job now is to prove the rightmost term approaches $||f - g^N||_p$. After this is done, we will have the inequality
$$
||f - f_n||_p \leq 2 ||f - g^N||_p.
$$
Then, letting $N \to \infty$ and using the mentioned lemma, the result is proven.

To prove that $||f_n - g_n^N||_p \to ||f - g^N||_p$ as $n \to \infty$, we note that
$$
||f_n||_p^p = \int_\mathbb{R} |f_n|^p \mathrm{d}\lambda
= \int_{E_N} |f_n|^p \mathrm{d}\lambda + \int_{E_N^C} |f_n|^p \mathrm{d}\lambda
= ||g_n^N||_p^p + ||f_n - g_n^N||_p^p,
$$
So that we have, by both assumptions made in (*ii*):
\begin{align}
||f_n - g_n^N||_p^p
&= ||f_n||_p^p - ||g_n^N||_p^p \\
&\to ||f||_p^p - ||g^N||_p^p \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} |f|^p \mathrm{d}\lambda - \int_{E_N} |f|^p \rm{d}\lambda \\
&= \int_{E_N^C} |f|^p \rm{d}\lambda \\
&= ||f - g^N||_p^p.
\end{align}

Comment: Caio, I think there is an issue with your double limit which made it look like the assumption that $\|f_n\|\to\|f\|$ is unnecessary.  Consider the case $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$ for a counter example.

Comment: You are right. I will try to fix it.

Comment: I think I got it!  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\varepsilon >0$,  and observing that
$$
  \int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^pdx = \lim_{N\to \infty }  \int_{[-N, N]}|f(x)|^pdx,
  $$
choose some $N\in {\mathbb N}$ such that
$$
  \Big|\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^pdx -\int_{[-N, N]}|f(x)|^pdx\Big|< \varepsilon ^p.
  $$
Let $\chi $ be the characteristicstic function of $[-N, N]$, put  $\tilde\chi  = 1 - \chi $, and notice that the inequality
above says that $\|\tilde\chi f\|<\varepsilon $.

Observe that for all $g$ in $L^p$ we have that
$$
  \|g\|^p =  \|\chi g\|^p+   \|\tilde\chi g\|^p, \tag{$*$}
  $$
because
$$
  \|g\|^p =
  \int_{\mathbb R}|g(x)|^pdx =
  \int_{[-N, N]}|g(x)|^pdx +
  \int_{{\mathbb R}\setminus [-N, N]}|g(x)|^pdx =
  \|\chi g\|^p+   \|\tilde\chi g\|^p.
  $$

We next claim that
$$
  \lim_n  \|\tilde\chi f_n\|  < \varepsilon .  \tag{$**$}
  $$
To prove it, plug $g=f_n$ in ($*$), leading up to
$$
  \lim_n  \|\tilde\chi f_n\|^p =
  \lim_n \|f_n\|^p - \lim_n \|\chi f_n\|^p =
  \|f\|^p - \|\chi f\|^p =
  \|\tilde\chi f\|^p <\varepsilon ,
  $$
where we have used that $\|f_n\|\to \|f\|$, and that $\chi f_n\to \chi f$ in $L^p$.

Next choose $n_0$ such that, for all $n\geq n_0$, on has that $\|\chi f-\chi f_n\|<\varepsilon $, and $\|\tilde\chi f_n\|  < \varepsilon $.  For all such $n$
we get
$$
  \|f-f_n\| $$$$ \leq
  \|f-\chi f\| +  \|\chi f-\chi f_n\| + \|\chi f_n-f_n\| $$$$ =
  \|\tilde\chi f\| +  \|\chi f-\chi f_n\| + \|\tilde\chi f_n\| < 3\varepsilon .
  $$
This concludes the proof.